# Python: how to tell if a string represent a statement or an expression?

Tags: python, expression, detect

I need to either call exec() or eval() based on an input string "s"

If "s" was an expression, after calling eval() I want to print the result if the result was not None

If "s" was a statement then simply exec(). If the statement happens to print something then so be it.

```
s = "1 == 2" # user input
# ---
try:
    v = eval(s)
    print "v->", v
except:
    print "eval failed!"
# ---
try:
    exec(s)
except:
    print "exec failed!"
```

For example, "s" can be:

```
s = "print 123"
```

And in that case, exec() should be used.

Ofcourse, I don't want to try first eval() and if it fails call exec()

Comment: What if the user inputs malicious code? And what *can* the user give as input (any Python code, or a "smaller" language)?

Comment: Hello Bart,

It is up to the user to type what he wants. I just provide a Python shell using my own UI

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to `compile` it as an expression. If it fails then it must be a statement (or just invalid).

```
isstatement= False
try:
    code= compile(s, '<stdin>', 'eval')
except SyntaxError:
    isstatement= True
    code= compile(s, '<stdin>', 'exec')

result= None
if isstatement:
    exec s
else:
    result= eval(s)

if result is not None:
    print result
```

Answer (score 6):

It sort of sounds like you'd like the user to be able to interact with a Python interpreter from within your script. Python makes it possible through a call to `code.interact`:

```
import code    
x=3
code.interact(local=locals())
print(x)
```

Running the script:

```
>>> 1==2
False
>>> print 123
123
```

The intepreter is aware of local variables set in the script:

```
>>> x
3
```

The user can also change the value of local variables:

```
>>> x=4
```

Pressing Ctrl-d returns flow of control to the script.

```
>>> 
4        <-- The value of x has been changed.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a feasible option. I provide a simple UI input box for the user to type the string.